# Make an existing row readonly while new row is editable Angular FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular9

I currently have a scenario as follow:

I have a `html table`, that is bound to a `Reactive Form's FormArray`.

The data returned from the server displays in the table, and should always be readonly. However, I want to be able to add a new row, which should be editable, for instance, contains input fields and dropdowns.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fcjm9u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) is a Stackblitz of an example, where I can add a new row, but it is also read-only.  I want the new row added, to contain editable input controls.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this:

You can add the  editiable property to a new user object and in your td rendering you have to look if is editable or not.
Pseudo code:

```
<td *ngIf="!user.editable">{{user.name}}</td>
<td *ngIf="user.editable"><input matInput ... ></td>
```

Or you can have an editableIndex in your component. -1 nothing is editable, else the index of the editable row.

```
<td *ngIf="editableIndex!==i">{{user.name}}</td>
<td *ngIf="editableIndex===i"><input matInput ... ></td>
```

Instead of two tds in the template, you can make your input readonly (or disabled for selects):

```
<td><input [readonly]="editableIndex!==i" matInput ... ></td>
```